# Countably infinite algebra

Tags: measure-theory

We know that a $\sigma$-algebra is either finite or not countable.
Can I find an algebra (field of sets) that is countably infinite?
I know that the proof for said theorem uses the fact that a $\sigma$-algebra is closed so countable unions, but I cant find an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X=\mathbb{N}$ and define $\Sigma=\{A\subseteq\mathbb{N}: |A|<\infty\}\cup\{A\subseteq\mathbb{N}: |\mathbb{N}\setminus A|<\infty\}$. You can easily check that this is an algebra. It is not a sigma-algebra because $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\{2n\}$ is a countable union of sets in $\Sigma$ which doesn't belong to $\Sigma$.

There are countably many finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, and so also countably many co-finite subsets. Thus $|\Sigma|=\aleph_0$.

Answer (score 2):

The algebra of finite-or-cofinite subsets of a set of cardinality $\kappa\ge\aleph_0$ has cardinality $\kappa$, therefore you can find algebras of any infinite cardinality.